# Category-Listing on Custom Page

Tags: magento2, module, category, custom, listing

I want to show the category-listing on a custom module-page. 
For example: `[url]/brandstore/index/listing/brand/1/category/10`

I tried to copy the content of the `catalog_category_view.xml` to my custom 
`brandstore_index_listing.xml` but i get an exception because the `current_category` is not defined in the registry.

Any suggestion for this issue?

Comment: Your brandstore module has its own block, controller, model?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom module with blocks, controllers and models

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I think I got a solution.

In my custom Block, I extend the Core Block

> \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View

And in the construct before calling the parent construct I set the **current_category** to my custom category.

If someone needs more details, let me know.